# Use of polynomial with reciprocals

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> Let $P(z), Q(z)$ be polynomials, and define $R(z)=\dfrac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$, where $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ have no common factors. Greater unity is achieved if we let the variable $z$ as well as the values $R(z)$ range over the extended plane. We may define $R(\infty)$ as the limit of $R(z)$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$, but this definition would not determine the order of a zero or pole at $\infty$. It is therefore preferable to consider the function $R(1/z)$, which we can rewrite as a rational function $R_1(z)$, and set $R(\infty)=R_1(0)$.

I don't understand why it is preferable to use $R_1$ instead of $R$. Since $R_1(z)=R(1/z)$, we have $R_1(\infty)=R(0)$ and $R_1(0)=R(\infty)$, so the two are, in a way, symmetric.

Comment: Infinity is so far away and hard to look at. By transforming infinity to zero, we can investigate the behaviour near it (e.g. order of zero or pole) more comfortably.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But at the same time that we transform infinity to zero, we also transform zero to infinity, don't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the text, the purpose is to determine the order of a zero or pole at infinity (or in fact define these notions in the first place).

As you may know, a rational function $R(z)$ has   a zero of order $k$ (or a pole of order $-k$) in $a\in \mathbb C$ if we can write $R(z)=(z-a)^kS(z)$ where $S$ is rational with $S(a)\ne 0$ and $S(a)\ne\infty$.
How could that make sense at infinity? Writing $R(z)=(z-\infty)^kS(z)$ does not make sense!

On the other hand, if $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is any Möbius transform, we note that the zero/pole oder of $R(z)$ at $f(a)$ is the same as that of $R(f(z))$ at $a$, provided $a$ and $f(a)$ are finite. This suggests and justifies *defining* the order of a zero/pole at $\infty$ to be the order of $z\mapsto R(1/z)$ at $0$.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now. At first I didn't quite understand the purpose of this transformation.